# Control over error codes in WSO2 DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

It is noticed that wso2dss-3.5.0 is giving `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error` for `VALIDATION_ERROR` or for `UNKNOWN_ERROR`
Is there a way that the status code can be changed according to these errors?
What I'm looking for is instead of giving 500 for all can't we have some other codes, for those validation errors.
And also why I'm facing this issue is, a message is sent by a message processor to the DSS service, and that message should be persist in the queue for `500 errors`, like service unavailable, but the message should be dequeued for other errors like validation errors.
What I was trying to do is providing the status code to `message processor` as it can handle that. Is there any other way I can get this done?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't define custom error codes in DSS. You have to do that in ESB level.